# for loop with char in string

Tags: objective-c, struct

**update 1**

Building on the previous update, I think I have a better insight into doing this, but I need the answer to this question. In the current `for` loop there is a variable named `tstring`. I need to do a  something like the following, but it does not work. I get the error `Collection expression type 'NSString *' may not respond to countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'` How can I fix this `for` clause?

```
for (NSUInteger i = 1; i < match.numberOfRanges; ++i)
        {
            NSRange matchedRange = [match rangeAtIndex: i];
            NSString* tstring = [string substringWithRange: matchedRange];
            for (char* suit in tstring){   // error here ********
            NSLog(@"char: %@",suit);}
            NSLog(@"range %lu string: %@", (unsigned long)i, tstring);
        }
```

**update 1**

**update 0**

Here is another approach, that does not require a search, but I still don't have any idea how to accomplish this approach in the context of the for loop.

I need a dictionary like the following schematic representation which associates with each card (2 to Ace) an integer from 0 to 12. (I think I know how to create a dictionary in C; maybe not in objective-c.)

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬──┬──┬──┐
│0│1│2│3│4│5│6│7│8│9│10│11│12│
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼──┼──┼──┤
│2│3│4│5│6│7│8│9│T│J│Q │K │A │
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴──┴──┴──┘
```

I need a struct with four nouns or arrays, I am not sure which, each of length 13 like this. This is similar to the original struct, but now the members are card suits, not players' positions.

```
struct board { 
int num;
char spade[13]
char heart[13]
char diamond[13]
char club[13]
};
```

Assuming the following deal of Board number 1,

`Q952.652.KJT4.95 T.KQT84.A865.J73 K8763.A7.Q.KQT84 AJ4.J93.9732.A62`

I need the following process in the for loop of my code.

```
   spade[10] = N
   spade[7] = N
   spade[3] = N
   spade[0] = N
   heart[4] = N
   heart[3] = N
   etc.
```

The question is, "How do you do that processing in a for loop?"

**update 0**

The following code is working for me but I need to alter it for the purpose described below. My console output (at least, the beginning) is provided below, also. From the output I need to retain results of range 1 and range 4 thru 19 in a special way.

The little table below contains range numbers in a 4 by 4 array with rows labeled Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs and columns labeled North, East, South, and West. When a Heart is selected, I need to search the contents of row H to determine whether that card is in N,E,S, or W and report the result. Notice that in the table the contents of each cell is a string containing either nothing (is empty) or a set of letters from '23456789TJQKA' and each row has all 13 letters somewhere in it. The numbers in the table just refer to the range number in the current output.

```
     N  E  S  W    
S    4  8 12 16
H    5  9 13 17
D    6 10 14 18
C    7 11 15 19
```

I would like to learn how to store the results in anticipation of the search task. Can I create a C struct for which each member contains the integer board number (a number between 1 and 36) and the 4 strings? For example would the struct below work? And if it does, how does one search in such a struct in objective-c? I could also use some help populating the struct in my loop.

```
struct board { 
int num;
char N[13]
char E[13]
char S[13]
char W[13]
};
```

Code excerpt follows.

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression  regularExpressionWithPattern:toMatch options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators error:&error];
NSLog(@"pattern length: %lu", (unsigned long)[toMatch length]);
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSLog(@"number of matches: %lu", (unsigned long)numberOfMatches);
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in [regex matchesInString:string options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])])
{
    NSLog(@"Number of ranges in match: %u", match.numberOfRanges);
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < match.numberOfRanges; ++i)
    {
        NSRange matchedRange = [match rangeAtIndex: i];
        NSString* tstring = [string substringWithRange: matchedRange];
        NSLog(@"range %lu string: %@", (unsigned long)i, tstring);
    }
}
```

Sample output follows.

```
2013-02-04 16:24:06.583 [71684:11303] string length: 22365
2013-02-04 16:24:06.591 [71684:11303] pattern length: 347
2013-02-04 16:24:06.602 [71684:11303] number of matches: 36
2013-02-04 16:24:06.613 [71684:11303] Number of ranges in match: 20
2013-02-04 16:24:06.613 [71684:11303] range 0 string:
[Board "1"]
[West ""]
[North ""]
[East ""]
[South ""]
[Dealer "N"]
[Vulnerable "None"]
[Deal "N:Q952.652.KJT4.95 T.KQT84.A865.J73 K8763.A7.Q.KQT84 AJ4.J93.9732.A62"]
2013-02-04 16:24:06.613 [71684:11303] range 1 string: 1
2013-02-04 16:24:06.613 [71684:11303] range 2 string: N
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 3 string: None
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 4 string: Q952
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 5 string: 652
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 6 string: KJT4
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 7 string: 95
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 8 string: T
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 9 string: KQT84
2013-02-04 16:24:06.614 [71684:11303] range 10 string: A865
2013-02-04 16:24:06.615 [71684:11303] range 11 string: J73
2013-02-04 16:24:06.615 [71684:11303] range 12 string: K8763
2013-02-04 16:24:06.615 [71684:11303] range 13 string: A7
2013-02-04 16:24:06.615 [71684:11303] range 14 string: Q
2013-02-04 16:24:06.615 [71684:11303] range 15 string: KQT84
2013-02-04 16:24:06.616 [71684:11303] range 16 string: AJ4
2013-02-04 16:24:06.616 [71684:11303] range 17 string: J93
2013-02-04 16:24:06.616 [71684:11303] range 18 string: 9732
2013-02-04 16:24:06.616 [71684:11303] range 19 string: A62
```

Comment: What is the "search task" here?  Finding a board that contains a specific card? We need some more details here.

Comment: There are 52 cards in each board, and 13 of each of Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, and clubs. When each of the 52 cards is `randomly` presented, one-at-a-time, the search is to find which person gets the card: North, South, West, or East.

Comment: And you want to look that up based on one of these `board` structures that has already been populated from a `[Deal ...]` line in the input?

Comment: Yes, or stored in another way that makes the 36 different boards searchable for this result.

Comment: I have a new approach. Please look at the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this question has strayed pretty far from "how do I do X?" and started to tread really close to "please do X for me." That said, I did think about it for a little while last night, and I had some thoughts to share that might be helpful to you as you move forward.

First, yes, this can be modeled with any number of C structs. You've already explored a couple of them. One thought that you haven't proposed yet would be to use a bitmap to represent hands. There are 52 cards in the deck; One way to store hands would be using a 64 bit integer, and making 52 of the bits correspond to cards in the deck. A hand contains a specific card if the bit corresponding to the specific card is set. Searching these hands then becomes a simple bitwise AND operation. You could even get creative with the interface, and use C `union`s to make the underlying representation be a 64 bit type while allowing structured access to subsets (like suits or positions) perhaps by saying that each suit corresponded to 16 bits of the underlying type.

That said, given the size of the data set here, there are relatively few ways to get into performance trouble, and after chewing on it for a bit, I started to feel like efforts to find the best or 'most quickly searchable' data structure constituted pre-mature optimization. Even if you made this application's data model a fully-blown out Objective-C object graph, with classes for the board, each position, each hand, even object instances for each card, you're still solving a "constant sized" problem (with an opportunity for "constant time" performance.) IIUC, there will never be more than 52 cards in the deck, nor more than 4 positions, nor more than 36 boards in a game. It's a pretty well-constrained problem. If you were planning to import tens of thousands of these games and then query across all of them, then the data structure you picked might start to matter, but at this point (ingesting one game) I feel pretty confident when I say that any Mac or iOS device would have no trouble digesting this problem with adequate performance even with the most brute-force of approaches.

Next, I would suggest abandoning the use of regular expressions in parsing the *contents* of the `[Deal "..."]` line. Could you use regexes? Sure. But it would be simpler to get the quoted string as a `const char*` (see `-[NSString UTF8String]`) and then go through the characters sequentially: First character is `[NSEW]` and identifies the first position (which will likely need to be stored in your structure, but is missing so far). Then a useless `:` to ignore. Then start reading cards for spades. When you hit a `.` increment the suit. When you hit a `<space>` increment the position. You *could* use regular expressions to pull out these parts, but the simple way is so much more straightforward, I'd suggest running with it. (I should mention, given the context, that this simpler way is also drastically faster, but I maintain that choosing this method solely for performance would be pre-mature optimization. So, don't choose this method for performance, choose it for simplicity!)

Lastly, I feel like I should mention that while my 2 minute google-fu has failed to find an open source, C PBN reading implementation (and hence model data structure) that was any good, I find it really hard to believe that there isn't one out there. My search was somewhat complicated by "bridge" being such an overloaded English word. I might suggest sniffing around some more and seeing if you can find a mature open source implementation to use either as is, or as inspiration, instead of rolling your own.

EDIT:

I wrote out one potential for loop to populate the structure you propose:

```
// Your structure, but as a typedef for clarity.
typedef struct {
    int num;
    char spade[13];
    char heart[13];
    char diamond[13];
    char club[13];
} board;

// The quoted string in the [Deal "..."] line; you already know how to get this.
NSString* dealString = @"N:A8.J762.KQ742.98 KQ53.K93.A85.T52 J97.A8.J963.J743 T642.QT54.T.AKQ6";

// Set up some arrays to use as maps between ints and chars...
// ...for positions:
const char* const positionIntToCharMap = "NESW";
int positionCharToIntMap['Z'] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0, len = (int)strlen(positionIntToCharMap); i < len; ++i) positionCharToIntMap[positionIntToCharMap[i]] = i;

// and cards:
const char* const cardIntToCharMap = "23456789TJQKA";
int cardCharToIntMap['Z'] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0, len = (int)strlen(cardIntToCharMap); i < len; ++i) cardCharToIntMap[cardIntToCharMap[i]] = i;

// and suits:
const char* const suitIntToCharMap = "SHDC";
int suitCharToIntMap['Z'] = { 0 }; 
for (int i = 0, len = (int)strlen(suitIntToCharMap); i < len; ++i) suitCharToIntMap[suitIntToCharMap[i]] = i;

const char* dealCString = [dealString UTF8String];
const size_t dealCStringLen = strlen(dealCString);

board thisBoard = { 0 }; 

if (dealCStringLen)
{
    char suit = 'S'; // start with spades
    char pos = dealCString[0]; // first character is starting position

    for (off_t i = 1; i < dealCStringLen; ++i)
    {
        if (dealCString[i] == ':')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (dealCString[i] == '.') // advance the suit
        {
            const int currentSuitInt = suitCharToIntMap[suit];
            const int nextSuitInt = (currentSuitInt + 1) % 4;
            suit = suitIntToCharMap[ nextSuitInt ];
        }
        else if (dealCString[i] == ' ') // advance the position and reset the suit
        {
            const int currentPosInt = positionCharToIntMap[pos];
            const int nextPosInt = (currentPosInt + 1) % 4;
            pos = positionIntToCharMap[ nextPosInt ];
            suit = 'S';
        }
        else // read the card
        {
            const char charForCard = dealCString[i];
            const int intForCard = cardCharToIntMap[charForCard];

            // Mark the current position in the appropriate array.
            if (suit == 'S')
            {
                thisBoard.spade[intForCard] = pos;
            }
            else if (suit == 'H')
            {
                thisBoard.heart[intForCard] = pos;
            }
            else if (suit == 'D')
            {
                thisBoard.diamond[intForCard] = pos;
            }
            else if (suit == 'C')
            {
                thisBoard.club[intForCard] = pos;
            }
        }
    }
}

// thisBoard is now populated.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with all you say, especially that the question has strayed a lot. I have the regex working, so I see no need to simplify it and you seem to agree. I think the processing needs are as you say, very constrained, and efficiency is not very necessary, for now. I think I can use the approach I outline in "update 0" with a dictionary and avoid the need for a search if I can populate the newer struct with  the values NESW in the correct positions. To do that I need help with the structure of the innermost for loop that will populate the struct, though. Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: My source on objective-c tells me that a string is really an array and that I can "walk through" an array with `indexOfObject:`. But I don't see how to "walk through" each string (and use each character in the string) that is produced by this loop because a string is also different from an array.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. `for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < tstring.length; ++i) {NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 1); NSLog(@"char: %@", [tstring substringWithRange:range] );}` [String Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/CreatingStrings.html)